# Migrate SQL Server 2000 data to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000, ssms

I want to migrate 2 database from my old SQL Server 2000 to my new server with the 2008 version.

I do that with the Management Studio 2008 with the export data task. It works fine and no error occurs but in the database on my new server all primary keys are missing.

Did anyone knows why or has another idea how to solve my problem.

Comment: If i show the properties of the connection in the management studio there is version = 8.00.760 and product = microsoft sql server desktop engine....i have not more informations about that server

Comment: So that's SQL Server 2000 with Service Pack 3a. Can't you just take a copy of the mdf and ldf and attach it? See [How to: Upgrade a Database Using Detach and Attach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189625(v=sql.100).aspx)

Comment: @MartinSmith is correct, and remember to set the compatibility level to whichever level you need (maybe you need it to remain in 2000 compatibility?)

Comment: thank you martin! this was the solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get to the **Select Source Tables and Views** step of the export wizard you need to do **Edit Mapping** for each selection, then select **Enable Identity Insert**. If you don't check this option the primary key values are not exported.